# Can't solve this: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, foreach

I am getting and error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in the code bellow. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am trying to access the sub array values [0] and [1] here. Just to mention that I have no idea now many values will be in the sub array.

I have placed a comment above of the offending line of code (where the error is)

```
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($mySessData);
  echo "</pre>";


Array
(
    [addtypeid] => 
    [isnew] => 
    [orderby] => 
    [geographicareaid] => 
    [catid] => 1
    [catid2] => 
    [manufacturerid] => 
    [modelid] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_from] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_to] => 
    [hoursused_from] => 
    [hoursused_to] => 
    [horsepowers_from] => 
    [horsepowers_to] => 
    [price_from] => 
    [price_to] => 
    [colorid] => 
    [isdamaged] => 
    [categoriesfilters] => 
    Array
        (
            [0] => 67
            [1] => 158
        )
)

 $sessData = array();
 $myresult = array();
 $val = array();   

 if (!empty($mySessData)){
     foreach ($mySessData as $sessData) { 
         // the line bellow is the offending line, where the error is thrown
         foreach ($sessData as $val) { 
             $myresult[$val]= $val; 

             foreach($filters as $f) {
                 if ($f['filterid'] == $myresult[$val]) {
                     $strWhere2 .= $myresult[$val] .",";
                 } // end if
             } // end of third foreach

         } // end of second foreach 
     } // end of first foreach
 } // end if
```

Comment: iterate conditional with `if (is_array($sessData)) { foreach ...`

Comment: your code did the trick. make it an answer, so I can accept it. thanks.

Comment: the code contains some non-sense, I strongly suggest you to read  example on the foreach documentation : http://php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you aren't checking if `$sessData` is actually an array. In fact, it's an array in only one case looking at your dump. Just add another `if (is_array($sessData))`

Comment: as i commented above, yes, that peace of code did the trick. user pce above posted that first, so credits goes to him. Thanks for the explanation. If he does not make his comment an answer, I will accept your answer, so the other user will find solution easier.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check if your value is an actual array before looping though it. The only value that is currently an array is [categoriesfilters]

Answer (score 0):

You have this variable `$sessData` might come empty from the bigger loop

and looping over it, in PHP <= 5.3 it will break:

Comment: i comment that line, and the error is still there, live and well :-(

Comment: within the inner loop add a condition: `if !empty($sessData) {...`

Comment: Sorry I meant the outer loop :D

Answer (score 0):

You have a "simple array" and you try to handle it as a multi dimensional array.

maybe you want to use `foreach($mySessData as $key => $val)` to fill the var `$myresult`, and use a `if (is_array($val))` to deal with categoriesFilter key.

I don't know what you exactly need, but this may help you :

```
 $myresult = array();

 if (!empty($mySessData)){
     foreach ($mySessData as $key => $val) { 
         // the line bellow is the offending line, where the error is thrown
             $myresult[$val]= $val; 
     }

     // I don't know what filters refers to, but I suppose you have to do something like this:
     $strWhere2 = '';
     foreach($filters as $f) {
       foreach($myresult['categoriesFilter'] as $categ_filter)
         if ($f['filterid'] == $categ_filter) {
           $strWhere2 .= $categ_filter .",";
     }
 } // end if
```